# Binding usage in Word Add-in

Tags: c#, binding, office-js, word-addins

I would like to use the Office Add-in technology to give to a Word document the Model-View-Controller logic.

In my scenario, the user should be able to create a new Word document, activate the Add-in and press a button inside the add-in to add a textbox field to the document. The field should display a number coming from the database: when the user updates that number and press save, the number should be written back to database. The next time the Word document is opened, the number should be refreshed, in order to display an updated value.

What I would like to know is whether the Add-in technology can be used (with binding support maybe?) or it is still in experimental stage. I'm having trouble trying to understand the best way to build a compact OOXML that simply represents my textbox: the method getSelectedDataAsync outputs a very complex document, it can't be the smarter way to describe a single-light-basic-poor-naked-textbox field! And how to set the binding to a custom XML? Where should that XML be placed? Inside the document? I looked at the samples provided on GitHub by Microsoft but they aren't so clear, since in many cases they're based on existing Word documents, which already have the necessary data and fields.

Comment: Hello Jeanie, i have a couple of questions on your case, to provide you better guidance. A) do you need a text field or its ok to just insert the content control? B) Regarding the update of the field, you will be able to update the field as long as the add-in is active. we dont support (as of august 2016) any events for save or open the document, you can update your backend either by exposing a button on the add-in to do so, or if the content of the control changes. please provide more details. thanks!  Juan Balmori PM for Word.js

Comment: Hi Juan, I erroneously called it "textbox": a "content control" would be great. So you're saying that there isn't a clean way to get notified when the predefined Save button is clicked? I'll have to add a custom Save on the add-in, since updating the backend whenever the content changes is not an option, it would happen too often. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Effectively, right now we don't have an event when the document is saved. And i am not sure if this is even desired, for instance in online clients we are allways saving the document in the background. yes i would recommend you for now to add a save options on your add-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely! The scenario you describe is actually one of the key types of add-in that the platform was originally designed for. The key element is a JavaScript object that we call a "Binding" that keeps track of a content control in the document, and there's no OXML or custom XML required.

The API is capable of adding a content control (similar to a text box) directly: call the [Bindings.addFromSelectionAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.addfromselectionasync) method.

```js
function addNewField(fieldName){
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync("text",
    { id: fieldName },
    function (asyncResult){
        displayNumberFromDatabase(asyncResult.value);
    }
}
```

Also [register for two event handlers](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.addhandlerasync) so that you receive notifications when the user selects or modifies the text inside those content controls. The relevant events in this case are [BindingSelectionChanged](http://dev.office.com/reference/reference/shared/binding.bindingselectionchangedevent.htm) and [BindingDataChanged](http://dev.office.com/reference/reference/shared/binding.bindingdatachangedevent.htm), respectively.

```js
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync("bindingDataChanged", whenBindingDataChanged);
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync("bindingSelectionChanged", whenBindingSelected);
```

When these events are triggered, you'll want to read the content. You can do that with the [Binding.getDataAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.getdataasync) method.

```js
function whenBindingDataChanged(eventArgs){
    eventArgs.binding.getDataAsync(function(asyncResult){
        setValueToDatabaseAsync(eventArgs.binding.id,asyncResult.value);
        // you need to implement setValueToDatabaseAsync
    });
}
```

And finally, to modify the contents of the Binding yourself to write the initial value, use the [Binding.setDataAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.setdataasync) method.

```js
function displayNumberFromDatabase(myBinding){
    getValueFromDatabaseAsync(myBinding.id, function(value){
        myBinding.setDataAsync(value);
    });
    // you need to implement getValueFromDatabaseAsync
}
```

-Michael Saunders, PM for Office add-ins

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks to your tips I wrote an example that works! I didn't understand how to use the binding, because I thought it worked differently: you have to write each set and get statement, while generally with binding you bind a control to an object and the control reflects the object's value and vice versa. Unfortunately it seems that Binding is not supported on Office online, do you have any news about it? As a second option, I could add a custom XML Part and create a mapping between that part and my content control: is it an option or do you think it's a deprecated solution?

Comment: depends on the type of binding that you create, text bindings are supported in online, the others will come soon.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for now!